# Using the output of an SQL statement in another SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the output from one SQL statement into another SQL statement, although it does not seem to be working. Is there an alternative, and how would I use it?

```
$id = ($_SESSION["user_id"]);
                $query1 = "SELECT event_id FROM booking where user_id = '$id'"; 
                $result = mysql_query($query1);

                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM event where event_id = '$result'";
                $results = mysql_query($query2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables, try using below syntax

```
SELECT event.event_id,booking.* 
FROM event
JOIN booking on event.event_id=booking.event_id
WHERE booking.user_id='$id';
```

Comment: +1 - barring some unusual circumstances, joins are to be preferred over multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

What's about using the one query instead of two:

```
        $id = ($_SESSION["user_id"]);
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM event 
                   where event_id IN (SELECT event_id 
                                        FROM booking 
                                       where user_id = '$id')";
        $results = mysql_query($query2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a single query, using a [sub-query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html), like this;

```
$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM event where event_id = (SELECT event_id FROM booking where user_id = '$id' LIMIT 1)"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This is only one db call rather than two, so more efficient.